# How exactly to use ResizeSensor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, resize

My goal is run a javascript function every time the size of an expanding textarea element changes, and from other questions I found this: http://marcj.github.io/css-element-queries/

I downloaded it and put the css-element-queries folder on the server, and included it in the header:

```
<script src="css-element-queries/src/ResizeSensor.js"></script>
<script src="css-element-queries/src/ElementQueries.js"></script>
```

Then in a javascript file that I'm using below, I have

```
ResizeSensor(document.getElementById('the_id'), function(){
console.log("resized");
the_function();
});
```

But it doesn't do anything and gives an error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at forEachElement (ResizeSensor.js:46)
    at ResizeSensor (ResizeSensor.js:201)

Comment: That means probably that `document.getElementById('the_id')` returns null. Also you need to call `new` on ResizeSensor, it's not a function, it's a constructor. so call `new ResizeSensor(...`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this library instead: https://github.com/sdecima/javascript-detect-element-resize

it's what the others are based on.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if ElementQueries are the correct solution for your issue.

Element Queries are used to apply specific CSS, if an element has reached a specific size.

E.g. the following is your HTML:

```
<div class="widget-name">
    <h2>Element responsiveness FTW!</h2>
</div>
```

and your define a CSS rule like that:

```
.widget-name h2 {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.widget-name[min-width~="400px"] h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.widget-name[min-width~="600px"] h2 {
    padding: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.widget-name[min-width~="700px"] h2 {
    font-size: 34px;
    color: red;
}
```

Now Element Queries do the following: If the container `widget-name` has the size of 700px or less the rule `.widget-name[min-width~="700px"] h2` is applied. if the size of the container `widget-name` is 600 or less the rule `.widget-name[min-width~="600px"] h2` is applied.

I hope this answer explained it a little bit.

Comment: I'm mostly need the resizeSensor. Wasn't sure if it also ElementQueries to run so i included both. I'm looking for something like the html oninput or onchange event, but for when the height or width changes (for example by dragging out a textarea).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when i was using sticky-sidebar plugin, finally i found the solution:

after import *ResizeSensor.js* you should use it like this:

```
import ResizeSensor from "resize-sensor";

window.ResizeSensor = ResizeSensor;
```